# Getting number of rendered features per range with PyQGIS?

Tags: pyqgis

I would like to know how many features are rendered in my `QgsGraduatedSymbolRendererV2` per range. I need to know also the exact range (lower and upper value).

I know how to get each range : `QgsVectorLayer.render().ranges()` but I can't get the feature count there.

I saw the function `QgsVectorLayer.featureCount(QgsSymbolV2)` but if I use the symbol that I got in `QgsRendererRangeV2.symbol()` it always returns 0. I used `QgsVectorLayer.countSymbolFeatures()` before, it returns `True`.

Can somebody explain if it's possible and how?

Comment: Did you use `countSymbolFeatures()` first? See [API doc](http://qgis.org/api/classQgsVectorLayer.html#ab030540514e6242ef91c422db2c46a47)

Comment: Yes. I used ``QgsVectorLayer.countSymbolFeatures()`` before, it returns True.